# Issue with leafletjs with L.polygon getting clipped

Tags: svg, leaflet

I'm using `L.polygon` to create some squares and stuff on my maps, but sometimes when I `pan` around with my mouse, the `fill` gets `clipped`:

[image: Clipped fill]

How can I avoid this?

The SVG for polygon is:

```
<path stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#0033ff" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="5" fill="#0033ff" fill-opacity="1" d="M-2247 -185L-2247 23L-27 23M-27 -185L-2247 -185"></path>
```

The main SVG element is:

```
<svg class=" leaflet-zoom-animated" width="2672" height="1002" viewBox="-3138 -821 2672 1002" style="-webkit-transform: translate3d(-3138px, -821px, 0);">
```

This happens both in `IE 9.0.8112.16421` and `Chrome 29.0.1547.76 m`.

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle showing the problem?  Hard to tell from the above what is the problem (there is probably some interaction with another element going on).

Comment: I've been trying to add create a fiddle with that, but it's not really working in the same way as my example, I don't use geo coordinates like this one does that I tried to recreate the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/NightNor/7r44R/6/